# Android MediaPlayer.stop() pauses instead of stopping

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have written two class wrappers for android.media.mediaplayer.

If I use the object from the factory MediaPlayer.Create(). then the mediaplayer object stops the song when it's method stop is called (this is, stop the song so when I call play(), it starts from the beginning of the song). But if I use the default constructor, stop() behaves exactly like pause() keeping the previous position in the song (except that it's really in the stopped state).

I had to use seekTo(0) after prepare() and stop() to do what I want, but this is not what the documentation says.

> public void start () Since: API Level 1
>
> Starts or resumes playback. If playback had previously been paused,
>   playback will continue from where it was paused. If playback had been
>   stopped, or never started before, playback will start at the
>   beginning.

So, if I call start() when it's stopped it should start from the beginning.

This is the code from the stopSong method from my class:

```
public void stopSong() {
    if(mpPrepared){
        mp.stop();
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.seekTo(0);
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me why is this happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(mp.isPlaying){

    try {
    mp.stop();
    mp.prepare();      
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

hope this help

Comment: I tested it, but still just pauses. I don't see how changing the conditional would change the stop() behavior. Thanks anyway.